# Simplify and upper bound of sum equal zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, upper-lower-bounds

Let $\beta_1$ , $\beta_2$ and $S$ real numbers, and $N$ and $M$ natural numbers.
Can we simplify this formula. 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sum_{m=0}^{NM-1}(-1)^{n+m}\binom{N-1}{n}\binom{NM-1}{m}
\beta_{1}\beta_{2}\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{\beta_{1}(n+1)+\beta_{2}(m+1)}{\beta_{1}(n+1)\beta_{2}(m+1)S}
\end{pmatrix} .$$
After simplification if there is any  upper bound for 
let
Because this sum  it equal zero.
Any solution please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\frac{a+b}{ab} = \frac 1a + \frac 1b$, your sum simplifies to 
$$\frac 1S\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sum_{m=0}^{NM-1}(-1)^{n+m}\binom{N-1}{n}\binom{NM-1}{m}\left(\frac{\beta_2}{n+1} + \frac{\beta_1}{m+1}\right)$$

Which further simplifies to 
$$\frac 1S\left[\beta_2\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}n(-1)^n\frac1{n+1}\right)\left(\sum_{m=0}^{NM-1}\binom{NM-1}m(-1)^m\right) \\+ \beta_1\left(\sum_{m=0}^{NM-1}\binom{NM-1}m(-1)^m\frac1{m+1}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}n(-1)^n\right)\right]$$

Values for each of the expressions in $(\,)$ can be found with a little searching (though actually, you really only need to find the value of two of them).

Comment: the problem for me this sum $$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}n(-1)^n$$ equal zero.

Comment: @Mokhtar - Hint: $$(x + 1)^K = \sum_{n=0}^K {K \choose n}x^n$$

Comment: hi @Paul Sinclair, how this well be help full for me thanks

Comment: @Mokhtar - compare the expression you are trying to show is 0 to the expression I gave (which is just an application of the binomial theorem). Figure out what values of $K$ and $x$ are needed in mine to make it look like yours. Then realize that mine says the value of the sum is $(x+1)^K$. What is $(x+1)^K$ for those values of $x$ and $K$ just determined.